# Angular ajax calls are cached in IE11

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-11

I am making similar get Ajax calls using angular $http for every 10 seconds,But the calls are being cached because of which i am not getting the updated data.
I have found the following solution to disable the cache.But adding this is working in IE and it is not working in chrome and mozilla.
Can you please provide the solution.

Below is the link

http://derpturkey.com/prevent-get-request-caching-in-angular/

Comment: I'd really rather not click that link.  Mind providing the snippet of code you know to be causing the problems here?

Comment: app.config(['$httpProvider',  
  function($httpProvider) {

    if(!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
      $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
    }          

    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["If-Modified-Since"] = "0";
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache";     
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common.Pragma = "no-cache";                     
  }
]);

Comment: You'll want to edit that into your question.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to prevent cache is to send another parameter in the URL.
If it's a get you can have something like this:

```
return $http({
                url: yourURL,
                method: 'GET',
                params: {someParameters, 'foobar': new Date().getTime()},
                headers: ...
            });
```

`'foobar': new Date().getTime()`

should make it working

Comment: Don't want to send the parameter.Is there any other solution?

Comment: Have you read the angular doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching